# Do I need iOS 9 or higher to test an app on an iPhone without a developer program plan?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

I can download the latest Xcode, but must I also be running at least iOS 9 to be able to develop an app and run it on my device without being a member of the developer program? I've got an iPhone 4 which cannot be upgraded any further from iOS 7.1.2.

Comment: Have you tried testing the application on your device yet?

Comment: @DanielStorm No, I need to choose a development platform first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is answered here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52904

No, I don't need iOS 9 as there is probably nothing on the iOS side preventing from using free provisioning. Xcode 7.3.1 supports iOS down to version 6, meaning I could test an app for free on a device with iOS 6.0.

Comment: You should include the major points from that link in your answer here. Links can stop working overtime.